# Is the rate function in Cramér's theorem (large deviations) continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, large-deviation-theory

In [Cramér's theorem (large deviations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_theorem_(large_deviations)), a rate function of random variable $Z$ is defined as
$$
\Lambda^*(x) = \sup_{t \in \mathbb R}(t x - \Lambda(t))
$$
where $\Lambda(t)$ is the [cumulant generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant) of $Z$.

My question is if $Z$ is bounded from below and above, is the function $\Lambda^*(x)$

- continuous?
- differentiable?
- $\frac{d \Lambda^*}{d x}(x) < \infty$?

I have checked a few examples and the answers seem to be positive. But I don't know how to do this for general $Z$.

Any reference on the properties of this function would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would start looking in "Large Deviation Techniques and Applications" by A. Dembo & O. Zeitouni. It should contain everything you need about rate functions.